# Use tikz to draw highlighted irregular shape around part of fraction

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I wanted to get some help to get this output around just a section of a fraction:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick,<-latex] (pic cs:markme) to [in=180,out=45] +(45:1cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] {Dipole};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{equation*}
M(z)=\frac{-0.7768(z-1.3)\tikzmark{markme}\tikz[baseline]{\node[draw=blue,fill=blue!20,anchor=base,
                                            ellipse,inner xsep=-1pt,inner ysep=0pt]
  (d13) {(z-0.9141)}}}{z(z-0.8)(z-0.9)}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: ![![enter image description here]

I've declared two nodes to be `remembered` and later on drawn a complex and transparent path over it. It could drawn behind the expression using a `background layer`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
M(z)=\frac{-0.7768(z-1.3)\tikz[baseline, remember picture]{\node[anchor=base, inner xsep=-1pt,inner ysep=0pt]
  (d13) {$(z-0.9141)$};}}{z(z-0.8)\tikz[baseline, remember picture]{\node[anchor=base, inner xsep=-1pt, inner ysep=0pt] (d14){$(z-0.9)$};}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[opacity=.5, rounded corners, fill=red!40] ([shift={(-1pt,1pt)}]d13.north west)-|([shift={(1pt,-1pt)}]d13.south east)--([shift={(1pt,1pt)}]d14.north east)|-([shift={(-1pt,-1pt)}]d14.south west)|-([shift={(-1pt,-1pt)}]d13.south west)--cycle;
\draw[blue,thick,-latex, shorten <=1pt] (d13.east) to [in=180,out=0] +(45:1cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] {Dipole};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you...how do you get rid of the arrow that is pointing down?

Comment: @Joe I've changed a little bit the arrow, is it better now?

Comment: I love the `remember picture` solution, nice work

Comment: Why don't put the `tikzpicture` environment before the `equation` one? In this way the equation highlighted wouldn't be dim...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Not sure to understand you. `tikzpicture` uses `d13` and `d14` which are defined on previous equation.

Comment: See my answer, that's what I intended. BTW, the `z`, etc. in your red area should be in math mode, see the difference in the fonts.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to put the `tikzpicture` environment before the `equation` one, like in the OP's question, you just have to run with `pdflatex` twice; the labels created by the `\tikzmark`s are recognized at the second run.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners] 
            ($(pic cs:mark1)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark1)+(0,10pt)$) -- 
            ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,10pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,-7pt)$) -- 
            ($(pic cs:mark4)+(2pt,6pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark4)+(2pt,-4pt)$) -- 
            ($(pic cs:mark3)+(0,-4pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark3)+(0,8pt)$) -- cycle; 
        \draw[blue,thick,-latex] ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,4pt)$) to [in=180,out=15] +(30:1cm) 
            node[anchor=west,text=black] {Dipole};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{equation*}
        M(z)=\frac{-0.7768(z-1.3)\tikzmark{mark1}(z-0.9141)\tikzmark{mark2}}{z(z-0.8)\tikzmark{mark3}(z-0.9)\tikzmark{mark4}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I understand it. Your solution works because you're using `tikzmark` while with `nodes` or even `tikzmark-subnodes` is not possible to make reference to them before their declaration.

Comment: The main problem with `tikzmark` is that it's only a `coordinate`, then you need to manually compute all relative points, while using a `node` already provides all needed anchors.

Comment: @Ignasi Of course, that could be a problem if you have a lot of points. But you also have the advantages that the equation remains as is (you forgot to put the descriptions of your nodes in math mode) and it is not covered by the color.