# How to combine equations and tikz to get helpful notes at equations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, equations, align

Is there any way to combine the helpful syntax of align environments with the graphical options of tikz? I am looking to reproduce equations that look like this picture:

[image: How to reproduce this in LaTeX?]

First equation:

```
\begin{align*}
    a^2=\Big(b\cdot \sin(\alpha)\Big)^2+n^2
\end{align*}
```

Second equation (the cloud one):

```
\begin{align*}
    h=b\cdot \sin(\alpha)
\end{align*}
```

Obviously it is rather hard to produce the exact same result. I would also be happy with an equation in a box with an arrow pointing to the =.

Do you have a good idea how to do it? With nodes it turned out pretty bad.

Comment: What have you tried? With [tikzmark](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikzmark/0) you can do basically whatever you like. For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375032/use-tikz-to-draw-highlighted-irregular-shape-around-part-of-fraction

Comment: BTW, why do you have `align*` without alignment points?

Comment: You could use the eforms package (and possibly others) to create pop-up notes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a TikZ solution without `tikzmark` that uses `amsmath`'s `\overset`/`\underset`/`\overunderset`.

While this doesn't produce a nice cloud yet it is the base of further customization, for example, like the one by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329053/16595).

For now, I settled on a rounded rectangle, gray color and smaller text.
By default, `amsmath` sets the over- and undersets in `\scriptstyle` which we could do, too, but I don't think it looks good.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  cloud eq/.cd,
  edge/.style={rounded corners=+2pt, arrows=Latex[round]-},
  c/.style={cloud eq/edge,anchor=north,to path={--++( +0pt,+-2ex)\tikztonodes}},
  l/.style={cloud eq/edge,anchor=east, to path={|-++(+-1ex,+-2ex)\tikztonodes}},
  r/.style={cloud eq/edge,anchor=west, to path={|-++( +1ex,+-2ex)\tikztonodes}},
  node/.style={at end, draw, rounded corners=+1pt}
}
\newcommand*\tikzoverunderInternal[3]{%
  \tikz[trim left=+0pt, trim right=+0pt]
  \draw[cloud eq/#1, #2] (0,0) to node[cloud eq/node] {$#3$}();}
\NewDocumentCommand\tikzUnderset{ O{l} m }{
  \underset{\tikzoverunderInternal{#1}{}{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\tikzOverset { O{l} m }{
  \overset{\tikzoverunderInternal{#1}{yscale=-1.2}{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\tikzOverUnder {O{l} m O{r} m}{
  \overunderset{
    \tikzoverunderInternal{#3}{yscale=-1.2}{#4}}{
    \tikzoverunderInternal{#1}{}{#2}}}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\tikzset{
  cloud eq/node/.append style={scale=.7},
  cloud eq/edge/.append style=gray}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{align}
    a^2 & \tikzUnderset{h = b \cdot \sin\alpha}{=}
            (b \cdot \sin \alpha)^2 \tikzOverset[r]{a+b}{+} n^2 \\
    c^2 & \tikzUnderset[c]{\vphantom{\int_i} E=mc^2}{=}
            a^2 + b^2 \tikzOverUnder[c]{\int_i e^i}
                           [r, overlay]{a^2 >0, b^2>0}{>} 0
\end{align}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command I made using some code that someone help mi eith in one question I made [Math notes between equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628845/math-notes-between-equations)

This is the command I made out of the post:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\umathnote}{ mm }
   {
     \overset % ❶
        {% The annotation goes above
          \textcolor{black!20!white}{\hbox to 0pt{\hss % ❷
             $ % return to math mode
               \begin{array}{c} % ❸
                   \displaystyle #2\\ % ❹
                   \Big\downarrow % ❺
               \end{array}
             $
          \hss}
          }
        }
        {#1} % 
   }
   
\NewDocumentCommand{\dmathnote}{ mm }
   {
     \underset % ❶
        {% The annotation goes above
          \textcolor{black!20!white}{\hbox to 0pt{\hss % ❷
             $ % return to math mode
               \begin{array}{c} % ❸
                   \Big\uparrow\\ % ❹
                   \displaystyle #2 % ❺
               \end{array}
             $
          \hss}
          }
        }
        {#1} % 
   }
```

You can see the results here:
[math note command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628941/math-note-command)

Comment: This looks like it could indeed be useful - you can improve the answer further by actually applying it to the situation asked about in the question and adding a screenshot of the result, to see how close it is to what the asker wanted.